# Calculating the date of previous day

Tags: mysql, date

im trying to sum up the values of the fields on a table, however one of the conditions is that the date, must be from the previous day, im trying to use sql curdate() but im so far unable to get it to work:

```
string varsql = "SELECT  sum(merc1)/2 as total 
                 FROM  wgcdoccab 
                 where tipodoc ='FSS' 
                 and serie='1' 
                 and contribuinte='999999990' 
                 and SELECT DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY);"; //division query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT sum(merc1)/2 as total 
FROM wgcdoccab 
where tipodoc ='FSS' 
and serie='1' 
and contribuinte='999999990' 
and date_column = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Comment: Thank you that did it!, my fault for being careless with syntax.